# Implementing Screenplay pattern for automated testing in swift

Tags: swift, design-patterns, automated-tests, bdd, xctest

I'm currently learning the screenplay pattern but i'm having trouble with the Given keyword.
For my current use case it seems that it should be a question.

```
Given(user).has(OpenedTheApplication.successfully())
```

has is defined as a task

```
func has(_ task: Task) {
    perform(task)
}
```

The gherkin keyword is defined as follows:

```
class Given: GherkinKeyword {
    func has(_ task: Task) {
        actor.has(task)
    }
}
```

So if I understand screenplay correctly then tasks should not create a query about the state of the system.

So rather I would like to define this:

```
Given(user).wasAbleTo(OpenTheApplication.toTheHomePage())
```

and then

```
func wasAbleTo(_ question: Question) {
    ask(question)
}
```

and the gherkin keyword is updated too:

```
class Given: GherkinKeyword {
    func has(_ task: Task) {
        actor.has(task)
    }
    func wasAbleTo(_ question: Question) {
        actor.wasAbleTo(question)
    }
}
```

is this a correct way of thinking for asserting that the application was launched correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assert on anything then that should be a 'Then', rather than a 'Given'. If you're concerned that any part of the setup (Givens) required for a test might not work, it's best practice to write a separate test to check those pieces of functionality. This will allow you to use whatever setup you need for more-complex tests without needing to assert (question) during the setup (Given) stage.

The Gherkin for the tests you need might look like this:

```
Scenario: Homepage is presented on app launch
When the user launches the application successfully
Then the user sees the homepage

Scenario: Navigate to search
Given the user has launched the application successfully
When the user navigates to the search page
Then the user sees the search page
```